# Android GMail App inflating images in HTML Email (nub)

Tags: android, html, email, gmail

So I am quite new to email marketing. I am tasked with creating a nice looking email for my client.

Please see first image:
(Excuse direct thinks, I can't post images for 10 rep points...)
http://i161.photobucket.com/albums/t203/photo240/Email_zpsad88b500.jpg

This is how my email should look (Note: this is unfinished, just as far as I have gotten so far.) It displays fine in Outlook, GMail desktop, iOS Mail, Apple mail and so on.

However, in the GMail Android App it does this:
http://i161.photobucket.com/albums/t203/photo240/Screenshot_2013-07-05-15-36-33_zps49a8e2b0.png

It seems to be rendering the social icons (which are their own slice) at full res whilst downsizing the rest so it fits on screen.

I'd like everything to downsize to fit on screen and in proportion to each other - can anyone help?

I'm sure it's a simple fix. I am reluctant to post my code as I've been trying to sort this all day so it's quite a mess right now - if/when I get a fix I'll need to rebuild to remain nice and clean..!

I appreciate any help, cheers!